# Optimize for a parameter across many different sites

Tags: r

I have data that looks similar to the following

```
Site Unknown_Parameter X Y Z Predicted Actual
A           2          3 4 2     5       6
A           2          4 3 2     7       5
B           3          6 8 9     12      9
B           3          4 6 2     10      10
```

etc...

I am trying to create a function that minimizes the RMSE of each site by determining the optimal value for the unknown parameter. I can do this for a single site at a time using the following pseudocode

```
fn <- function(unknown_parameter) {
df$Predicted <- calculations with unknown_parameter and X Y Z
RMSE <- sqrt(mean((df$Predicted - df$Actual)^2))
RMSE
}
optimize(fn, c(1,10))
```

I am able to obtain the optimal value for the unknown parameter as well as the RMSE for a single site, but I would like to scale this to do it for every site since I have 100s. Ideally, I would want my output to look like the following

```
Site Optimal_Value RMSE
A    1.7           2.45
B    1.2           3.24
C    1.3           9.21
```

etc...

I have been trying to use the split command, but this transforms my data into a list, and I'm not really sure how to work with it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your psuedocode does not show single *Site* filter but runs on whole dataframe.

Comment: So for the single site, I ran this line before hand for a proof of concept: df <- df[!(df$Site != 'A'),]

I am now trying to use the split command, but I am not sure how to proceed: 
df2 <- split(df, df$Site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `split` produces a list of subsetted dataframes by the input factor's value, consider `by` that also subsets the dataframe by one or more factor(s) but can also pass the subset into a function. And to bind all dataframes together run a `do.call(rbind, ...)` on returned list.

```
# USER-DEFINED METHOD RECEIVING subsetted df AS INPUT AND RETURNING dataframe AS OUTPUT
subset_process <- function(subdf) {

   fn <- function(unknown_parameter) {
      subdf$Predicted <- calculations with unknown_parameter and X Y Z
      RMSE <- sqrt(mean((subdf$Predicted - subdf$Actual)^2))

      return(RMSE)
   }

   opt <- optimize(fn, c(1,10))

   tmp <- data.frame(Site = subdf$Site[[1]],
                     Optimal Value = opt,
                     RMSE = fn)
   return(tmp)
}

# SPLIT + RUN METHOD ON EACH SUBSET
df_list <- by(df, df$Site, FUN=subset_process)

# APPEND ALL DF ELEMENTS INTO MASTER DF
final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

Comment: Error in data.frame(Site = subdf$Site[[1]], Optimal_Value = opt,  : 
  object 'subdf' not found


I am getting this error when I am running the assignment for tmp. What should I be passing in as subdf?

Comment: I also get this error when I run the df_list line


 Error in data.frame(Site = df$Site[[1]], Optimal_Value = opt,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Comment: I managed to fix the two previous errors, but what I am getting is the exact same value and RMSE for each site. I believe that the by command is not properly subsetting the data and is instead running the function on the entire dataset for each site.

Comment: I got it to work. Forgot to change df to subdf. Thank you so much!

Comment: Correct. Change all dataframe instances inside the function to the argument, *subdf* as I have here using your pseudocode. Glad to help. Happy coding!